# Joomla custom registration script with profile fields

Tags: php, joomla, registration

I've a joomla's custom registration script and it works without problems but now I want add some 'profile' fields like address and cellular number.

This is my code:

```
<?php
if( $_POST["name"] || $_POST["email"] || $_POST["username"] || $_POST["password"] ){
     define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
     define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );
     define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
     require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
     require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

     $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
     $app->initialise();
     require_once(JPATH_BASE.DS.'components'.DS.'com_users'.DS.'models'.DS.'registration.php');

     $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
    $extension = 'com_users';
    $base_dir = JPATH_SITE;
    $language_tag = 'it-IT';
    $reload = true;
    $lang->load($extension, $base_dir, $language_tag, $reload);

     $model = new UsersModelRegistration();
     jimport('joomla.mail.helper');
     jimport('joomla.user.helper');

     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $email =  $_POST['email'];
     $block = '0';
     $sendEmail = '1';
     $activation = '';
     $data = array( 'username' => $username,
     'name' => $name,
     'email1' => $email,
     'password1' => $password, // First password field
     'password2' => $password, // Confirm password field
     'sendEmail' => $sendEmail,
     'activation' => $activation,
     'block' => 0 );
      echo $model->register($data);
}
?>
```

I've added this code:

```
'profile.address1' => $indirizzo,
     'profile.city' => $citta,
     'profile.phone' => $cellulare,
```

but It doesn't work...

How can I add the profile db fields into this registration script?

Thanks at all.

Answer (score 0):

For starters I strongly recommend using the joomla's `Jinput` to retrieve request data and not `POST`. You can find more info on this [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput).

The `profile` you are using is not working because the object is not carrying the data you want. Depending on your joomla version check where the `$indirizzo, $citta, $cellulare` belong and access the object that has them.

I'd suggest instantiating the `$user` object and then retrieving what you want like so `$user = JFactory::getUser();` . These links will help you [Accessing the current user object](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_current_user_object) and [JFactory/getUser](http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getUser).

Comment: In the links there isn't any reference to profile fields.
I added `$profile = JUserHelper::getProfile($user->id);` and I can read an user field but I can't create new id fields into user_profiles db.